# Problems with using live in jQuery - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` which gets dynamically populated with `paragraph tags` (they don't exist initially). I want each of this newly dynamically added `<p>` to perform something when being clicked on - i.e. have a click event attached to them.

The only way that I know how to do this is by using `live` and `delegate`.

```
$('div.fromSelected p').live('click', function () {
    $("&ltp>" + $(this).text().substr(3) + '&lt/p>').appendTo('.fromOptionList');
    //$(this).parent().remove();
    $("#auto_box").getNiceScroll().resize();
    $(this).remove();
    $("#auto_box2").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

However after some time of invoking the `click` event on the dynamically added paragraphs I get the following error:

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

What will circumvent this problem?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is this correct, or a formatting problem? `&ltp>`

Comment: if you know how to use `delegate` why are you using `live`? As you are using 1.7.2, it'd be worth using `.on` instead

Comment: I am using on but I am getting the same problem after a certain number of clicks ... Let us say twenty in a row

Comment: how many 'div.fromSelected' elements are there exactly?

Comment: Twenty ... On each click I put them in another div. The other div also dynamically adds this click event on the newly added paragraphs. Would calling <code>die</code> explicitly help with this matter?

Comment: You don't need to call `.live` multiple times, once is enough in this case. Don't call it every time you add another element.

Comment: It seems that my other plugin <code>getNiceScroll.resize()</code> is causing the problem. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Could you post the code that adds all the <p>?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.on` instead:

```
$("div.fromSelected").on('click', 'p', function () {...
```

Comment: @imparator can you post your html or set up a http://jsfiddle.net that showcases the problem?